# Can I use a Galileo Gen 2 6 pin FTDI 3V3 Serial to USB cable with the raspberry pi?

Tags: serial, serial-console

I have a 6 pin Serial to USB cable from FTDI (TTL-232R-3V3). Here is the spec: http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_TTL-232R_CABLES.pdf

It works on the galileo gen 2 board.

I know that the FTDI cable for raspberry pi has only 3 cables (http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_TTL-232R_RPi.pdf), for Rx, Tx and Gnd.

Can I use the TTL-232R-3V3 6 pin cable to connect to the RPi via serial interface? I'm not sure, but why shouldn't[image] it work if I just connect Rx, Tx and Gnd?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer is it depends (on what is at the other end).
The Pi only outputs 3.3v signals, but assuming the converter is powered from USB it should work provided the system at the other end has the appropriate driver.

Provided the interface is 3.3v give it a try, it won't hurt.

Comment: The cable says at the USB end 3.3V... so it will be ok. Will give it a try.

Comment: It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it and it worked perfectly.

Just connect the Rx from the cable to the Tx of the GPIO, then connect Tx on the cable to the Rx of the GPIO. Finally connect the ground.

On my mac, I can login via serial using this command:

```
screen port_name 115200
```

from this here: http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection

Comment: Your question asked about serial interfacing, and what you have done will work. If your intention was to get access to the Pi command line from a PC there are better and easier ways to do so. `ssh` will use the network connection and not require any additional cabling or connection. I use `ssh pi@PiIPaddress` and you can use `zeroconf`` and/or Public Keys to make it easier.

Comment: of course, but you'll need direct access for special things, like if you install a new linux version that has no ssh enabled. there are other uses for this procedure, but I normally use ssh as you said.